# How to map all requests except existing files to a handler

Tags: apache, .htaccess, handler

Need some help with htaccess rewrite rule I'm stuck with.

I have a handler index.html which is used to handle all requests except existing files. 
I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

But I have some filenames **similar** to the requests to be handled. If there comes a request to /main it has to be handled by index.html but because of existing file with extension - main.asdfjaskldfjaskdfjasfd.js - I'm getting 404 error insted of handling.

This problem is super easily solved in nginx with one liner: "try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;" but I don't have an opportunity to use nginx on production - only Apache.

So I need some help with those rules. 
Tried (besides tens of other) this:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^ /index.html
```

Full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(demo-auth|api|oauth|password|login|logout|register|images)
RewriteRule ^ laravel.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^ /index.html

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add that, at the top of your htaccess, to disable MultiViews:

```
Options -MultiViews
```

The [Apache docs on mod_negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_negotiation.html), describes what the Multiviews Option does, when enabled:

> If the
>   server receives a request for /some/dir/foo and /some/dir/foo does not
>   exist, then the server reads the directory looking for all files named
>   foo.*, and effectively fakes up a type map which names all those
>   files, assigning them the same media types and content-encodings it
>   would have if the client had asked for one of them by name. It then
>   chooses the best match to the client's requirements, and returns that
>   document.

Comment: Yeah... It was Multiviews' fault. It was AWS and it has some specific configuration. For example, it was by default in Debian but it doesn't on AWS. So I've put this option to htaccess and everything went fine. Thanks!@